# Having 2 or more one-to-many relationships between 2 tables

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have following class:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public IEnumerable<B> Bs1 { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<B> Bs2 { get; private set; }
}
```

I want `A` to have two relationships with `B` and I don't want multiple FKs on `B` for table `A`.

I would like to define B as:

```
public class B
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int AId { get; private set; }
    public BType Type { get; private set; }
}
```

how then I can configure using Fluent API that `Bs1` should contain only `B`s of a given `BType.Type` and `Bs2` should contain `B's` of other type? I would like to avoid client side fitlering.